# cannot find file on my usb flash drive

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

My USB flash drive doesn't working fine but I cannot find a video file on it (looks as a hidden file), the used space is 7 GB but when I select all files it's just 3 GB.

What I tried is to show the hidden files and protected operating system files with no results. also I tried to see the files from the CMD commands with no hope.

The video working fine when I connect it to my T.V I need to recover this videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the flash memory file system was FAT32,
I opened it using ubuntu live CD, and i found my files.